# Chrome (69) and User timing

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I can remember seeing User timings after using the performance.mark and measure calls. Now there is a scenario this could really help me out, but I cant find the user timing section anywhere in the performance tab. Is this not available anymore?

TIA, 
john.

Answer (score 0):

If the site has instrumented user timing marks, you can find it in the Performance tab, below the Interactions panel. It will be not displayed if there are no timing marks.